# What is the performance of std::atomic vs non-atomic variables?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, thread-safety, atomic

I am curious as the the performance of using `std::atomic<float>` vs a normal `float` in an application. I am also curious as to what affects this. I often see topics on the performance of atomics vs a mutex, but I have found it harder to find information on atomics vs non-atomics.

I am not using this as a way to choose to make my code thread-safe or not, just wanting to understand the overhead involved.

*(EDIT: At this point in the original question I gave an example (see below) that was supposed to be illustrative of a change of implementation rather than ask a specific question about that code. This seemed to confuse people about what I was asking so I have taken it out.)*

I basically want to know what the broad factors are that affect performance of std::atomic. Is it the platform? The way they are used? Is it slower to use atomics accessed approximately the same amount by two threads rather than if one thread accesses them 95% of the time and the other one only occasionally?

Also, is there any difference between a `std::atomic<int>` and a `std::atomic<float>` in this regard?

Thanks in advance,

Adam

---

Example from original question:

<s>Basically, I tried making a million floats and writing values to them 200 times. This took 0.87 seconds for me. Once I changed them to `std::atomic<float>`, this took about 2.5 seconds. So this implies it is about 3x as expensive to use `std::atomic<float>`.</s>

<s>I tried this but for reading values rather than writing, and found that a normal `float` and `std::atomic<float>` take the same amount of time.</s>

<s>But is this affected by other things? If another thread is writing/reading to my atomics, does this slow other reads/writes to the same variable down? Presumably so, but how can I understand this better?</s>

Comment: You need to write test.  We need to see the tests, the results and the compilation options. Oh and it's probably platform/tool-chain specific as well. see also: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_lock_free

Comment: AFAIK, this is highly dependent on the platform. Even on one platform, it can vary wildly depending on how you use or abuse them.

Comment: Sure, but my test is only to illustrate my question, not to ask why that specific piece of code has that specific result. I'm asking for some theory on the computational cost of atomics, rather than feedback on my code

Comment: It can vary greatly between platforms.  On my platform, std::atomic operations take about x40 longer than non-atomics.

Comment: Why do you care what the performance is?  `std::atomic` should be used to provide synchronization between threads.  If you need a `std::atomic<float>` to prevent a data race then use it.  If you do not need to prevent a data race then just use a `float`.

Comment: In a large application you can have many different solutions to problems, one of which may be simpler and involve atomics, and others that may not involve atomics but be more complex. Understanding the performance trade-offs helps you to decide which approach to take

Comment: SMTC - Show Me The Code. It is moot to talk about performance of *some* unknown code on *some* unknown platform.

Comment: @SergeyA - there is no code, this isn't a question about code not working or a specific solution. It is a simple question - what are the factors affecting the performance std::atomic ?

Comment: You are saying that you experienced triple slowdown with atomic - show us the code and mention the platform.

Comment: @SergeyA - it's irrelevant to the question. Finding that some specific platform circumstance or implementation affected a specific piece of code doesn't answer the question of what the broad factors are that affect performance of std::atomic. It's ok if you don't know the answer

Comment: If you're headed in the direction I believe you are, you're right. The costs of synchronizing threads can easily exceed the benefits of threading. Sadly the only way for anyone to tell you if this is the case is on a case by case basis. My rule of thumb is write the one that's easiest to get right and maintain and profile. If the results aren't up to snuff, try the other. If the results are good enough, who gives a smurf if the other is faster?

Comment: I do not know the answer to an unasked question. There are millions of reasons why in your test atomics would perform slower. Simple example - writing to global variable million times in a row. Without atomic, it would be a single write of the last value. With atomic, it would be million fenced writes. Makes difference, but I won't speculate about your code which you have not shown.

Comment: The broad factors are: how it's implemented on your platform, is it lock-free on your platform and what is the memory architecture on your platform.

Comment: Thank you @RichardCritten :)

Comment: @RichardCritten and I repeat - the benchmark code is a king.

Comment: @SergeyA see the 1st comment

Comment: Atomic variables are much slower than non-atomic ones. But how much? It depends on the exact conditions (CPU, contention - contention matter a **lot**, etc.). So really, you need to try out them. If they don't perform well, then you need to try out other solutions. (just some data: as I remember - I did this test some years ago - incrementing an atomic int was 25x slower, if there was no contention. If there was high contention, it was more than 100x slower).

Comment: It is highly hardware-dependent.  Using `std::atomic` disables optimizations, thus guaranteeing certain properties. What you really want is to learn about the kind of optimizations that compilers and CPUs do that cause race conditions. The big headaches are caching and instruction reordering. The latter can happen at the compiler, CPU, and memory subsystem level. And for both, reading a variable is totally different than writing one.

Answer (score 17):

Atomic stores without ordering parameter (i.e. the default) are expensive because of additional ordering instructions that are issued by the compiler.
On `X86`, a default (sequentially consistent) atomic store to a float would look like this:

```
atomic<float> f;
f.store(3.14);
```

gcc produces the following instructions:

```
0x00000000004006d0 <+0>:     movl   $0x4048f5c3,0x20096a(%rip)        # 0x601044 <f>
0x00000000004006da <+10>:    mfence
```

The `mence` instruction is expensive because it ensures direct visibility to other cores (i.e. the causes the store buffer to be flushed).

You can try to run a test without ordering:

```
f.store(3.14, std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

This will get rid of the `mfence` and probably show a significant difference in performance. It is closer, if not equal on some platforms, to non-atomic stores.

> is there any difference between a `std::atomic<int>` and a `std::atomic<float>` in this regard?

On the assumption that both are lock-free, probably not. The ordering constraints are responsible for the reduced performance.

Comment: If there is no contention there is no reason to use atomic.  If there is contention, then you can't compare atomic to non-atomic, since non-atomic doesn't work.   So the comparison of "performance" is meaningless.

Comment: This is true in a single instance - but in a larger application you can choose multithreaded and single-threaded solutions to things and understanding the overheads associated with the tools you use for multi-threading let you work out which is the best approach.

Comment: @stark: If you want to cross a lake, you have to go with a ship. If you want to travel on a road, you need to go with a car. So the comparison of their speed is meaningless.

Comment: But if you want to go from point A to point B, and there is both a lake and a road in between them. You have a choice of either crossing the lake using a ship or travelling on the road using a car. You want to go the fastest way. The comparison of their speed in that context sure is meaningful.

Comment: It is completely reasonable to ponder the cost of atomics, for example in order to reason about whether algorithms are worth parallelising. But I guess it's easier to act high and mighty and tell the OP why his question is (supposedly) nonsensical. Sadly this is all too common on SO nowadays.

Comment: of course it makes sense to ask what the performance implications of atomic instructions are.

Comment: It's definitely a good question if you are designing a multi threaded code and have several options for designing the concurrent access to the floats. (such as atomics vs an intermediate queue or buffer).

Comment: Even if there is contention, as this answer points out using a relaxed memory ordering can increase performance while maintaining atomicity, if the contending variable can be updated after all the currently pipelined caches are exhausted.